# How to prove that $\mathrm{var}(X-E(X|Y)) \leq \mathrm{var}(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, covariance

I tried to solve this exercise but got stuck: Assume we have the random variables $X$ and $Y$ where $E(X) = 0$. How can we prove the following inequality $\operatorname{Var}  (X-E(X|Y)) \leq\operatorname{Var}(X)$?

I tried to write out the rhs: $\operatorname{Var}(X-E(X|Y)) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(E(X|Y)) - 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,E(X|Y))$
Since $E(X) = 0$, we have $\operatorname{Var}(E(X|Y)) = E(E(X|Y)^2)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X,E(X|Y)) = E(X*E(X|Y))$.

Thus we have $\operatorname{Var}(X) + E(E(X|Y)^2) - 2E(XE(X|Y)) \leq \operatorname{Var}(X)$ giving
$E(E(X|Y)^2) \leq 2E(XE(X|Y))$

But that did not get me anywhere as you can see, does anybody have any tips? OR do you think there might be a typo in the exercise?

Comment: Hint: Start rather from $$X=(X-E(X\mid Y))+E(X\mid Y)$$ hence $$\mathrm{var}(X)=\ldots$$

Comment: Tnx for the reply! However, it didnt get me anywhere.  I tried expanding, but nothing cancelled, care to give another tip? =)) $Var((X-E(X|Y)) + E(X|Y))  = Var(X-E(X|Y)) + Var(E(X|Y)) -2Cov(X-E(X|Y),E(X|Y)) $

Comment: Let us turn to the covariance then (with a factor $+2$ instead of $-2$), which involves three terms: $$E((X-E(X\mid Y))E(X\mid Y))\qquad E(X-E(X\mid Y))\qquad E(E(X\mid Y))$$ What can one say about each of these terms?

Comment: Opps +2 and not -2 , as you said, however, i still do not see how this track gets me anywhere: We have $E(X-E(X|Y)) = 0$ and $E(E(X|Y)) = 0$ and finally $Cov(X-E(X|Y),E(X|Y)) = E((X-E(X|Y))E(X|Y)) = E(XE(X|Y))-E(E(X|Y)^2)$ But this will only yield my original $E(E(X|Y)^2)<2E(XE(X|Y))$ :(

Comment: What you are lacking is a characterization of $E(X\mid Y)$ (until now, everything you tried would work with another random variable instead, which is a bad sign, right?). So, what is specific about $Z=E(X\mid Y)$, which makes that $E(XW)=E(ZW)$ for every $W$ such that $____$? IOW, **how do you define $Z$?**

Comment: Tnx for the quick reply! As far as I can tell the Z should be considered just another random variable where $E(Z) = E(E(X|Y)) = E(X) = 0$ in this case?  I do not see the implications of $E(XW) = E(ZW)$ for every W(W is a random variable i suppose?) :(

Comment: Again: **how is the random variable $E(X\mid Y)$ characterized?** I am asking for properties of $E(X\mid Y)$ that $E(X\mid Y)$ is the only random variable to satisfy. You should have provided these from the start, or at least have had them in mind, but oddly it seems impossible to make you simply state them. Why ask a question involving conditional expectations, then? Imagine a post asking about some fine property of *prime numbers* and its author being unaware of what being a prime number actually means...

Comment: Ye i misread your comment, i do not understand your conclusion. I wrote the exercise in its entirety, thus there are no more characterizations of $Z = E(X|Y)$ to give other than the general definition of a conditional expectation. We do know however that  $E(Z) = E(E(X|Y)) = E(X) = 0$. Thus if the inequality is proven with out using any other property of conditional expectations, it holds for any random variable Z where $E(Z) = 0$. So from your latest answer it seems that your answer is rather:"Yes there is a typo/lacking info in this exercise"?

Comment: "it seems that your answer is rather:"Yes there is a typo/lacking info in this exercise"?" Absolutely not (and how you managed to reach this conclusion frankly baffles me). "other than the general definition of a conditional expectation" **Which is what?** (For the third or fourth time.)

Comment: A general remark, as a 10th comment in a thread which should have 1 or 2 at the most: you see fit to fight every inch of my suggestions, to avoid giving the definitions your question entails. Doing so, you might hope a full solution ready to be handed in, will appear on the page (and you might even be right to believe so since these things do happen, unfortunately). But be aware that such a behaviour might also lead some users to believe that you are not coming to the site in good faith, with the logical consequences such a belief may have regarding the answers you may hope to receive here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Did's hints are spot on and you don't need $E(X)=0$.

---

Let $Z=E(X|Y)$, consider
$$
\text{Var}(X)=\text{Var}(X-Z+Z)=\text{Var}(X-Z)+\text{Var}(Z)+2\text{Cov}(X-Z,Z).
$$
Note that
\begin{gather}
E(X-Z|Y)=E(X-E(X|Y)|Y)=E(X|Y)-E(X|Y)=0\\
\implies E(X-Z)=0\implies \text{Cov}(X-Z,Z)=E[(X-Z)Z].
\end{gather}
In going from the first line to the second line, we have used the Law of Iterated Expectations:
$$
E(X-Z)=E[E(X-Z|Y)]=E(0)=0.
$$
For $E[(X-Z)Z]$, we can condition on $Y$ again:
$$
E[(X-Z)Z|Y]=ZE(X|Y)-Z^2=Z^2-Z^2=0\implies E[(X-Z)Z]=0.
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\text{Var}(X)=\text{Var}(X-Z)+\text{Var}(Z)\geq\text{Var}(X-Z)=\text{Var}[X-E(X|Y)].
$$

Comment: I think the OP has problems understanding the implication: $E(X-Z|Y) =0 \Rightarrow E(X-Z)=0$.